# How to create and write to an XLSX file on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm having trouble with my XLSX file process on Google Cloud Storage. The following code is what I have so far:

```
import cloudstorage

mime = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
filehandle = cloudstorage.open('/default/temp_export.xlsx', 'w', content_type=mime)
filehandle.write('some data1,some data2\n')
filehandle.write('some data3, somedata4\n')
filehandle.close()
```

This will create an XLSX file `temp_export.xlsx` on my storage bucket with the XLSX format using the mime type. When I tried reading the file with the following command, it works fine:

```
import cloudstorage

filehandle = cloudstorage.open('/default/temp_export.xlsx')
print filehandle.read()

# Output:
# some data1,some data2
# some data3, somedata4
```

But when I tried going to my storage bucket and downloading the temp_export.xlsx and try to open it, it throws this excel error:

```
Excel cannot open this file.
The file format or file extension is not valid. 
Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that 
the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: refer to below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715977/how-to-write-to-xlsx-file-on-google-cloud-storage/54746884#54746884

Comment: @eric chan: have you solved your problem? I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for not using the [latest library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) for Cloud Storage? That one is only for App Engine with Python 2.7.

There is [an example here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) on how to upload an object and [how to download it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code_sample), and then you must read your `xlsx` file with a proper library for it, like [the ones mentioned here](http://www.python-excel.org/).